# How to test "this" calling context with jest?

Tags: jestjs

How does one test in `jest` that a function is called with the right `this` context?

I only was able to find how to test for arguments passed in, with [toHaveBeenCalledWith](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-). But it doesn't test `this` context, and I can't find any other API for this or examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**JEST**

Create a [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) of the function then use [`mock.instances` to check the value of `this`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-property).

```js
test('the value of this using Jest', () => {
  const foo = {
    name: 'foo',
    func: function() {
      return `my name is ${this.name}`;
    }
  }
  const mockFunc = jest.spyOn(foo, 'func'); // spy on foo.func()

  expect(foo.func()).toBe('my name is foo');
  expect(mockFunc.mock.instances[0]).toBe(foo); // called on foo

  mockFunc.mockClear();

  const bar = {
    name: 'bar',
    func: foo.func // use the func from foo
  }

  expect(bar.func()).toBe('my name is bar');
  expect(mockFunc.mock.instances[0]).toBe(bar); // called on bar
});
```

**SINON**

For better semantics [`Sinon`](https://sinonjs.org/) provides direct access to `this` using [`thisValue`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/spy-call/#spycallthisvalue).

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

test('the value of this using Sinon', () => {
  const foo = {
    name: 'foo',
    func: function() {
      return `my name is ${this.name}`;
    }
  }
  const spy = sinon.spy(foo, 'func'); // spy on foo.func()

  expect(foo.func()).toBe('my name is foo');
  expect(spy.lastCall.thisValue).toBe(foo); // called on foo

  const bar = {
    name: 'bar',
    func: foo.func // use the func from foo
  }

  expect(bar.func()).toBe('my name is bar');
  expect(spy.lastCall.thisValue).toBe(bar); // called on bar
});
```

Comment: That's what you call a pseudo-test. I had something similar working already, but I was hoping that `jest` had support for something as essential as `this` context. It is strange that they wouldn't have it.

Comment: @vitaly-t yeah, after [looking at the source](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c93e02718480b9f25b0d28f33456ed159bd11b69/packages/jest-mock/src/index.js#L344) it really feels like `instances` is meant to track the instances created by a constructor function [like it says in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockinstances) and wasn't intended to be used to give back `this` for normal functions.  I updated my answer to include `Sinon` which has direct and documented support for testing `this`.